# Get formatted text from div to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to extract formatted contents of div element using JS and passing it to a hidden variable.
So far I have read all questions on stackoverflow regarding this topic, it seems like I have found a solution, it has actually worked once, but all of a sudden it stopped working and I can't find a way of making it work again.

I look for the easiest solution without AJAX, DOM etc.

My code:

```html
<?php

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=parek', 'parek', 'parek');
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (isset($_POST['aktualita'])) {

  $datum = date('d. m. Y');
  $jmeno = $_POST['jmeno'];
  $text = $_POST['text'];

  $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO aktuality (datum, nazev, text) VALUES ('$datum', '$jmeno', '$text')");
  $insert->execute();

  $message = "Aktualita byla úspěšně zveřejněna";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); window.location.replace('/');</script>";
}



?> <style>
  button {
    background-color: #e6c63b;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  form {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  }

  input[type=text],
  input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px 0;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }

  .cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
  }

  .container {
    padding: 25px;

  }
</style>
<center>
  <h1> Přidávání aktualit </h1>
</center>

<form action="addarticle.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="container">
    <label for="jmeno">Název aktuality:</label>
    <input type="text" name="jmeno" id="jmeno">
    <label for="editor">Text aktuality:</label>
    <input id="text" name="text" type="hidden">
    <div id="editor">
      <h1>Nadpis aktuality</h1>
      <p>Text aktuality</p>
      <p><br></p>
    </div> <button type="submit" name="aktualita">Přidat aktualitu</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
  var contentText = document.getElementByClassName('ql-editor');
  var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('text');

  // copy the text to input when the user writes in contentText div contentText.onkeyup = function() {
  hiddenInput.innerHTML = this.innerHTML; // 'this' is pointing to contentText }; 
</script>
```

The script I posted is a separate file which I am including in a pop up window on the main page.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please format your code properly. Having multiple statements on one single line makes the code very hard to read and follow. Stick to one statement per line (new line after each `;`). The CSS and HTML also has some formatting issues. You should always make sure your question/code is easy to read, or less people will even try and read it.

Comment: You can put this through a PHP/HTML beautifier first.

Comment: Why are you setting `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, this isn’t a file upload form.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, unfortunatelly none of them helped me a bit in my problem.